# How to batch deliver Gmail inbox and labels/categories?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is there a way for Gmail (or an extension) to delivery new messages in bulk at pre-specified times or upon request. It would be like 'send/receive' with the receive on pause. Ideally, I would like this for specific categories (Promotions, Social) as well as Labels. I would imagine the only approach for specific subset of mail received would be an extension or filter.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user four times.

Answer (score 0):

You don't control the receipt of messages.  HTML Gmail doesn't reach out for its messages and check if there are new ones. Messages are available once received by Gmail's servers and directed to your mailbox.

It's a bit different than having a locally installed mail client that reaches out to a server to check mail. In this case the mail client and the mail server are closely connected.